# Exercise about tensor product

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products, algebras, formal-power-series, polynomial-rings

Let be $R$ a $\mathbb{C}-$ algebra and take $R\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\mathbb{C}[[t]]$, Is this isomorphic as ring to $R[[t]]?$ I think that I can prove it using the quozient of these ring and take the projective/inverse limit, where the quotient is made with ideal like $(t^{n})$

Comment: In general, given commutative field $K$, unital $K$-algebra $A$ and monoid $M$ satisfying the finiteness condition required to form the so-called *large* algebra $A[[M]]$, the canonical morphism of unital $K$-algebras $A \otimes_K K[[M]] \to A[[M]]$ is always injective and has dense image in the canonical topology of the codomain however it will not be surjective in general. The particular case of power series, when $M=\mathbb{N}$ (with respect to addition) and $A$ is infinite dimensional over $K$ is one in which the canonical morphism is *not* surjective.